# Magento 2 - Render custom product collection via list.phtml

Tags: magento-2.1, custom, product-collection, render

The product grid of a category page (frontend) is rendered via layout in **catalog_category_view.xml**.

Lets say I have a custom product collection (which I got via

```
ProductRepositoryInterface::getList($searchCriteria) method
```

in a custom block class and want to render this collection. The rendered result should be displayed as a product grid on frontend (just like any category page).

How can this be done ?

By looking into `catalog_category_view.xml` there are two significant lines, which are responsible for rendering a product collection:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

How can I provide my custom product collection to these template files, so they render my collection ?

Correct me, if I am wrong on this.

This is how my block code looks like:

```
<?php
namespace Mod\Mod1\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Main extends Template
{
protected $_filterBuilder;
protected $_filterGroupArray;
protected $_filterGroupBuilder;
protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;
protected $_productRepository;
protected $_productFactory;
protected $_list;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    array $data = [])
{
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->_filterGroupBuilder = $filterGroupBuilder;
    $this->_filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getLoadedProductCollection(){
    $searchCrit = $this->buildSearchCriteria('','','','','','5-',1);
    $list = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCrit);
    return $list;
}
public function buildSearchCriteria(...){
....
return $searchCriteria;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to replace products on a category page or how to essentially have another version of the category controller?

Comment: Pagination and layer navigation never come right if you edit collection in list.phtml or corresponding block. So make sure the answer you're accepting does both of the things above.Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

Update your catalog_category_view.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
<block class="Your(Mod)\Namespace(Mod1)\Block\YourBlockFileName(Main)" name="your.category.products.list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/yourFile.phtml" />
</block>
```

And call yourFile.phtml in product/list.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('your.category.products.list'); ?>
```

Now, you can use your function in yourfile.phtml like this:

```
$block->yourfunction();
```

Example:

```
$block->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be:

Update your `catalog_category_view.xml` and replace `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` with `Mod\Mod1\Block\Main`

before:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

after:

```
block class="Mod\Mod1\Block\Main" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

Your `Main` class MUST extend `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

Then you will need to rewrite the method `getLayer()` to your own.

> FYI: your class `Mod\Mod1\Block\Main` needs some refactoring.

Create your own new `Layer` class that will extend `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer` and play around with the collections.

```
/**
 * Retrieve current layer product collection
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
 */
public function getProductCollection()
```

and

```
/**
 * Initialize product collection
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
 */
public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
```

Comment: Where is the block here? What is in `Mod\Mod1\Block\Main.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Basically initially you want to create a controller or even a basic CMS page so you have a page to show your collection.

From there you can use your custom block which creates your collection combined with the **list.phtml** template file to render the products on your page.

```
{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\ProductCollection" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" name="specialproducts"}}
```

Add above xml where **Vendor\Module\Block\ProductCollection** is the custom block code where your collection is created to xml for that page.

The **list.phtml** file gathers the collection from your block with below line of code:

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

So long as your block has the **getLoadedProductCollection()** function returning your collection of products the **list.phtml** file will then loop through each product in your collection rendering them in a default Magento product grid.

For your block code try updating below line to include **getItems()**:

```
$list = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCrit)->getItems();
```

Comment: I did as you said. My block has the ' getLoadedProductCollection()' function which returns 'ProductRepositoryInterface::getList()'. But I get an Error : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults::count() in ...  Looks like this is not the right approach.

Comment: see updated post

Comment: Maybe try changing $list = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCrit)->getItems();

Comment: @shahirhajir Did you try with getItems?

Comment: Not working. $list = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCrit)->getItems(); returns ProductInterface[] array and this array has no count()  funtion.     Uncaught Error: Call to a member function count() on array in ...\list.phtml on line 22.   On line 22 in list.phtml we have: $_productCollection->count()

Comment: Yeah ive just checked and getting the same. I do not normally use search criteria for product collections however list.phtml doesn't seem to work this way.

Comment: Looks like I have to render my product list with my own template

Comment: Why are you using the search criteria method? I want to learn a bit more about it now but thought it was more for API's.

Answer (score -2):

You can render product collection in your phtml file like this

> $product_collection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();

Comment: Not helpful at all

Comment: not helpful . .

Comment: To make this answer complete, you should share how `getLoadedProductCollection()` is defined inside your Block class, as well as sharing any other definitions on which this function depends. Additionally, you should display the structure of all files shared.